# Laravel passport dynamic scopes

Tags: php, laravel

is there a way to set the dynamic scopes of laravel passport instead of typing manually?

I tried to create a table(MySql) with scope name and description, created a model Scope, but that model is not working in AuthServiceProvider

```
Passport::tokensCan([
           'view-dashboard' => 'View the contents of dashboard',
           'view-reports'   => 'View the detailed reports'
       ]);
```

How can i make the scopes dynamic ? i want to manage the scopes based on roles of users by creating some interface

Edit: I could relate the solution to my present situation, and it really makes sense but can you just help we with the code of line

```
$token->scopes = user_scopes;
```

i am getting an Exception error `Attempt to assign property scopes of non-object` in the user model as i have added your code in my User class as mentioned. Can you just clear me how can i fetch the scope ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like:

1. Create a user_scopes table attached to your users which has the scopes you want to assign to that user
2. Overload the withAccessToken() method in your user Class, which is part of the HasApiTokens trait. Use this hook to pull your scopes from the database for that user and assign them to the access token:

```
public function withAccessToken($accessToken)
    {
        $this->accessToken = $accessToken;

        $token = $this->token();
        $token->scopes = $this->user_scopes;
        $token->save();

        return $this;
    }
```

If you want full flexibility, try extending and overriding the src/Bridge/ScopeRepository class

```
// in App\Providers\AppServiceProvider:

use App\ScopeRepository;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Passport\Bridge\ScopeRepository as PassportScopeRepository;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(PassportScopeRepository::class, ScopeRepository::class);
    }
}
```

Follow here for the complete details. https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/195

Comment: i have updated the question, can you help me with that ?? @Vikash

Comment: I want to fetch the scopes from database. How will the above answer would work for me ? i have gone through the github link you have provided. where should i write the withAccessToken method ? from where i should access the scopes from db ?

Comment: @techguru `$this->user_scopes` will automatically pull the data from `user_scopes` table... if you have defined the relationship with `user`<=> `user_scopes`... got it?

Comment: Ya i got it now , thanks i ll try and get back to you

Comment: `withAccessToken` is never executed! I tried to `dd()` and nothing happened